# How to use android activity fragement of already existing activities?

Tags: android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

Please see below the explanation of existing scenario and problem statement:

**Existing scenario:** I have set of activities in my application, one activity displays list of items and on click of each item, it will display another activity which consists of details of clicked item.
I need to support portrait and landscape mode for this activity which displays list of items and when it is there on portrait mode, it displays list of items perfectly and upon click on each item it displays another activity but in landscape mode it looks weird.

**Problem Statement:** when I rotate the screen in landscape mode, it shows each rows very large, obviously it covers whole screen so row is large and it doesn't look good.So I thought of changing this in such a way that when it displays on landscape mode, left side it should display the list of items and when user clicks on the item, right side it should display other activity which consists of details of clicked item.

**My doubt is:** If I use fragment then how it will impact on existing code? what are things I need to keep in mind while supporting fragment on existing code?
What I know is, I need to create one separate layout where left side will be one fragment with list of items(can't we put already existing activity which shows in portrait mode in left side fragment?) and right side will be another fragment where  activity with item details will be displayed Or is it some other way do i need to achieve this?

Please provide your valuable input on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the android sample project WifiDirect.